# How to avoid multiple Switch case statements

Tags: java, spring, java-8, switch-statement

I need to refactor a code that uses multiple case statements based on the queryString value it receives. Everytime a new query is added , we had to add a new case statement. Can we try to simplify it and make it more generic so that we dont have to keep on adding new case statements? Below is the code snippet

```
      switch (queryRequestRecevied) {
        case query1:
            reply = processQuery1();
            break;

        case query2:
            reply = processQuery2();
            break;

        case query3:
            reply = processQuery3();
            break;

        case query4:
            reply = processQuery4();
            break;

        case query5:
            reply = processQuery5();
            break;

        case query6:
            reply = processQuery6();
            break;

        default:
            reply = processInvalidQuery();
            break;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name for the operation you're looking for is *Replace Conditional with Polymorphism*: Instead of having `switch` or `if` statements, use a common interface for your cases and invoke that. I'm presuming here that your query returns some value and using `Supplier`; if not, use another functional interface or create your own.

```java
Map<String, Supplier<QueryResult>> queryProcessors = new HashMap<>();

...
// in a constructor or similar place
queryProcessors.put(query1, this::processQuery1);
queryProcessors.put(query2, this::processQuery2);

// in your handler method
var result = queryProcessors.getOrDefault(query, this::processInvalidQuery).get();
```

To decouple even further, you can do this:

```java
// declare some Spring beans implementing this interface
interface QueryProcessor {
  String getQuery();
  QueryResult processQuery();
}

// in your service class
Map<String, QueryProcessor> queryProcessors;

@Autowired //(not necessary for a single constructor)
MyService(Collection<QueryProcessor> queryProcessors) {
  this.queryProcessors = queryProcessors.stream()
    .collect(toMap(QueryProcessor::getQuery, identity()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't give enough code to see what could be factorized / more generic.

But at least instead of testing your input query you could declare 1 endpoint per query in your @Controller then no need to Switch / case testing.